# Anyway of minimizing references to selfies when refactoring to class based design?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, refactoring, design-principles

I'm in midst of refactoring a large set of python files and merging various methods into classes for modularity.

However, the use of `self` everywhere is quite daunting. It's impossible to change every variable reference using regexes since it's context sensitive. Is there a way to speed it up (or not add self everywhere)?

For example:

**Before refactoring**

```
def my_func():
  W = P + Kp + S + M + R
```

Each of the variables above is needed by multiple methods and hence I decided to put them as data members of the class. So now, it's `self.W, self.P, ...`

**After Refactoring**

```
class classifedData: #no pun intended
 def __init__(self, data):
   self.W = data['W']
   self.P = data['P'] #and so on

 def my_func():
   self.W = self.P + self.Kp + self.S + self.M + self.R #too much self?
```

However, this requires a major overhead for making changes across huge files.

Questions:

1. Is there an easier way? Can the `self` somehow be 'scoped' with `with` to make this easier?
2. Or is converting this to classes a bad idea and the overhead is what I must bear OR just refactor it as well structured procedural code? I.e., simulating a class like organization at the module level.

I'm fairly new to python and am working on some scientific/math intensive code base that needs to be refactored for maintainability and am not sure how to handle/incorporate the reference to `self` at numerous locations?